# Independed Child Task Execution

Tags: c++, tbb

I'm working with TBB for the first time and want to run a sequence of tasks that are all independent. I wanted to use tbb::task::enqueue, i.e. I create a root task and it creates a child task that is independent of the parent. This child can create a task again and so on.

My solution does not work, because the child task calls the parent again and I get an endless cascade. The execution of the root task works, but as soon as a child is created, there is an endless cascade.

```cpp
// initialization
tbb::task::enqueue( *new( tbb::task::allocate_root() ) tbbwrapper::ctask( <some data> ) );

// execute method
tbb::task* ctask::execute()
{
    <execute data processing>

    return <data result correct> 
    ? new( this->allocate_child() ) tbbwrapper::ctask( <result data> ) 
    : NULL;
}
```

I have a lot of tasks (all are independent and the execution order is also completely independent) to run and each task can create a successor, but it is completely undependent and just needs to be added to the queue to run. Also I don't need Wait or similar, because the execution should run in the background.

I just need a simple example to show me how this works.

Comment: If your tasks are all independent, do not create child tasks; create a new "root" task instead and enqueue it.
Also note that the tasks submitted via `task::enqueue` are scheduled via a shared work queue, not via work stealing.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is not recommended to use TBB task API directly because it is over-complicated and contains a lot of hidden problems. If you know the number of the tasks in advance, you may want to use `tbb::parallel_for`. If you want to add tasks during algorithm execution, you can use `feeder` functionality of `tbb::parallel_do`. If you do not want to use algorithms and want to manipulate with tasks, consider using `tbb::task_group`.

Do not you need to wait for background work completion even when the application ends? You can use `tbb::task_group` to create a background task, e.g.

```
tbb::task_group tg;
// Run parallel_for in background.
tg.run( [] { 
    tbb::parallel_for(...);
} );
// ...
// Any other code
// ...
tg.wait(); // task_group requires to call `wait` to guarantee that all tasks are really processed
```

If you want to guarantee a concurrent execution of background work, you can enqueue the only one task that will create additional work with other TBB algorithms.

**[UPDATE]**

Consider the `run_task` helper that runs a function in background.

```
#include "tbb/task.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <typename F>
class task_wrapper : public tbb::task {
    F f_;
public:
    task_wrapper(F f) : f_(f) {}
    tbb::task* execute() override {
        f_();
        return NULL;
    }
};

template <typename F>
void run_task(F f) {
    tbb::task::enqueue(*new(tbb::task::allocate_root()) task_wrapper<F>(f));
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        run_task([i] {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        });
    }

    // Give time to proceed the background tasks.
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the number of tasks, because they result from the runtime parameters. That this threads or thread group does not have to wait, the task only has to be executed in the background. I am basically looking for a similar system as the workstealing pool under Java https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool-- as a cross-platform library for C++.
My impression is that TB is the wrong library for this.
What are the alternatives?

Comment: I've added an example to my initial answer that demonstrates the approach how to use TBB as a some sort of workstealing pool.